# How to properly cluster with HDBSCAN for 1D dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, hdbscan

My dataset below shows product sales per price ([link to download dataset csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OlKdkB7kocuTBWz-07d8SiQ8IvVt2_RX/view?usp=sharing)):

```
     price      quantity
0    5098.0        20
1    5098.5        40
2    5099.0        10
3    5100.0        90
4    5100.5        20
..      ...       ...
290  5247.0       150
291  5247.5        30
292  5248.0       150
293  5248.5        20
294  5249.0        55

[295 rows x 2 columns]
```

**What I want to achive is clustering the dense regions (rectangles below) using HDBSCAN and sklearn**. We have four regions, but regions 3 and 4 could also be grouped into a big region, which would lead to only 3 regions on the entire dataset by changing the parameters **min_cluster_size** and **min_samples** in the function call.
[image]

And here is my code:

```
import hdbscan
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv')

price = group['price'].values.flatten()
price = price[:,np.newaxis]
weight = group['quantity'].values.flatten()

kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1.5).fit(price,sample_weight=weight)
#the multiplication factor is only for visualization purposes
data['prob'] = np.exp(kde.score_samples(price))*85000

fig = px.line(data,x='price',y='prob')
fig.add_bar(x=data['price'],y=data['quantity'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
data = data[['price','quantity']]

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=4,min_samples=8)
clusterer.fit(data)
data['cluster'] = clusterer.labels_

fig = px.bar(data,x='price',y='quantity',color='cluster',orientation='v')
fig.show()
```

[image]

**The problem is the result, the clustering did not work as expected (picture above x below)**. It clustered the amplitudes, not the dense regions as it mentions in the [algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-hdbscan-and-density-based-clustering-5fd79329c1e8). What am I missing in the code?
[image]

I've tried the follwing things: normalizing the data (both axis) and also swaping the axis before calling the HDBSCAN class.
Any help would be appreciated. I'm kind of lost in this code, but I thought by reading the documentation that it would be straight forward for this particular problem, as HDBSCAN deals great with density and noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've implemented this, you are actually trying to cluster 2-D data.  This make more sense when you visualize the result of your clustering as a scatter plot:

[image: scatter_clustering]

In order to cluster the 1-D data as I believe you're intending, you could reshape the data.  Essentially, you want a single list of prices where each `price` value is repeated in the list `quantity` times.  This is pretty straightforward with numpy:

```
data_1d = np.array(np.repeat(data.price, data.quantity)).reshape(-1, 1)
```

which gives

```
array([[5098.],
       [5098.],
       [5098.],
       ...,
       [5249.],
       [5249.],
       [5249.]])
```

Then you can cluster on this numpy array directly, but you need to significantly increase `min_cluster_size` and `min_samples` because you have way more values to cluster now:

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=5000, min_samples=200)
clusterer.fit(data_1d)
```

Finally, we can combine the cluster labels, pick the label that occurs most frequently*** for each `price`, and group by `price`:

```
clustered_data_1d = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((data_1d, clusterer.labels_.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1), columns=['price', 'cluster'])
clustered_data_1d['quantity'] = 1
grouped_data_1d = clustered_data_1d.groupby('price').agg({'cluster': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], 'quantity': np.sum}).reset_index()
```

To verify that we got what we expected, let's plot:

```
fig = px.bar(grouped_data_1d, x='price', y='quantity', color='cluster', orientation='v')
fig.update_traces(dict(marker_line_width=0))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Looks like the clusters generated by HDBSCAN with otherwise default parameters are largely similar to what you expected, though I'm sure you could tweak these a bit if you need fewer clusters for your final application.

*** *Using the 'mode' or the most commonly occurring cluster label may be a bit lazy on my part.  You could also consider taking a mean and rounding, or finding the lowest and highest `price` with each label and using those as cluster endpoints, or something else entirely!*

---

*Full code to copy-paste for those wishing to replicate:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hdbscan
import plotly.express as px

data_dct = {'price': {0: 5098.0, 1: 5098.5, 2: 5099.0, 3: 5100.0, 4: 5100.5, 5: 5101.0, 6: 5101.5, 7: 5102.0, 8: 5102.5, 9: 5103.0, 10: 5103.5, 11: 5104.0, 12: 5104.5, 13: 5105.0, 14: 5105.5, 15: 5106.0, 16: 5106.5, 17: 5107.0, 18: 5107.5, 19: 5108.0, 20: 5108.5, 21: 5109.0, 22: 5109.5, 23: 5110.0, 24: 5110.5, 25: 5111.0, 26: 5111.5, 27: 5112.0, 28: 5112.5, 29: 5113.0, 30: 5113.5, 31: 5114.0, 32: 5114.5, 33: 5115.0, 34: 5115.5, 35: 5116.0, 36: 5116.5, 37: 5117.0, 38: 5117.5, 39: 5118.0, 40: 5118.5, 41: 5119.0, 42: 5119.5, 43: 5120.0, 44: 5120.5, 45: 5121.0, 46: 5121.5, 47: 5122.0, 48: 5122.5, 49: 5123.0, 50: 5123.5, 51: 5124.0, 52: 5124.5, 53: 5125.0, 54: 5125.5, 55: 5126.0, 56: 5126.5, 57: 5127.0, 58: 5127.5, 59: 5128.0, 60: 5128.5, 61: 5129.0, 62: 5129.5, 63: 5130.0, 64: 5130.5, 65: 5131.0, 66: 5131.5, 67: 5132.0, 68: 5132.5, 69: 5133.0, 70: 5133.5, 71: 5134.0, 72: 5134.5, 73: 5135.0, 74: 5135.5, 75: 5136.0, 76: 5136.5, 77: 5137.0, 78: 5137.5, 79: 5138.0, 80: 5138.5, 81: 5139.0, 82: 5139.5, 83: 5140.0, 84: 5140.5, 85: 5141.0, 86: 5141.5, 87: 5142.0, 88: 5142.5, 89: 5143.0, 90: 5143.5, 91: 5144.0, 92: 5144.5, 93: 5145.0, 94: 5145.5, 95: 5146.0, 96: 5147.0, 97: 5147.5, 98: 5148.0, 99: 5148.5, 100: 5149.0, 101: 5149.5, 102: 5150.0, 103: 5150.5, 104: 5151.0, 105: 5151.5, 106: 5152.0, 107: 5152.5, 108: 5153.0, 109: 5153.5, 110: 5154.0, 111: 5154.5, 112: 5155.0, 113: 5155.5, 114: 5156.0, 115: 5156.5, 116: 5157.0, 117: 5157.5, 118: 5158.0, 119: 5158.5, 120: 5159.0, 121: 5159.5, 122: 5160.0, 123: 5160.5, 124: 5161.0, 125: 5161.5, 126: 5162.0, 127: 5162.5, 128: 5163.0, 129: 5163.5, 130: 5164.0, 131: 5164.5, 132: 5165.0, 133: 5165.5, 134: 5166.0, 135: 5166.5, 136: 5167.0, 137: 5167.5, 138: 5168.0, 139: 5168.5, 140: 5169.0, 141: 5169.5, 142: 5170.0, 143: 5170.5, 144: 5171.0, 145: 5171.5, 146: 5172.0, 147: 5172.5, 148: 5173.0, 149: 5173.5, 150: 5174.0, 151: 5174.5, 152: 5175.0, 153: 5175.5, 154: 5176.0, 155: 5176.5, 156: 5177.0, 157: 5177.5, 158: 5178.0, 159: 5178.5, 160: 5179.0, 161: 5179.5, 162: 5180.0, 163: 5180.5, 164: 5181.0, 165: 5181.5, 166: 5182.0, 167: 5182.5, 168: 5183.0, 169: 5183.5, 170: 5184.0, 171: 5185.0, 172: 5185.5, 173: 5186.0, 174: 5186.5, 175: 5187.0, 176: 5188.0, 177: 5188.5, 178: 5189.0, 179: 5189.5, 180: 5190.0, 181: 5190.5, 182: 5191.0, 183: 5191.5, 184: 5192.0, 185: 5192.5, 186: 5193.0, 187: 5193.5, 188: 5194.0, 189: 5194.5, 190: 5195.0, 191: 5195.5, 192: 5196.0, 193: 5196.5, 194: 5197.0, 195: 5197.5, 196: 5198.0, 197: 5198.5, 198: 5199.0, 199: 5199.5, 200: 5200.0, 201: 5200.5, 202: 5201.0, 203: 5201.5, 204: 5202.0, 205: 5202.5, 206: 5203.0, 207: 5203.5, 208: 5204.0, 209: 5204.5, 210: 5205.0, 211: 5205.5, 212: 5206.0, 213: 5206.5, 214: 5207.0, 215: 5207.5, 216: 5208.0, 217: 5208.5, 218: 5209.0, 219: 5209.5, 220: 5210.0, 221: 5210.5, 222: 5211.0, 223: 5211.5, 224: 5212.0, 225: 5212.5, 226: 5213.0, 227: 5213.5, 228: 5214.0, 229: 5214.5, 230: 5215.0, 231: 5215.5, 232: 5216.0, 233: 5216.5, 234: 5217.0, 235: 5217.5, 236: 5218.0, 237: 5218.5, 238: 5219.0, 239: 5219.5, 240: 5220.0, 241: 5220.5, 242: 5221.0, 243: 5221.5, 244: 5222.0, 245: 5222.5, 246: 5223.0, 247: 5224.5, 248: 5225.0, 249: 5225.5, 250: 5226.0, 251: 5226.5, 252: 5227.0, 253: 5227.5, 254: 5228.0, 255: 5228.5, 256: 5229.0, 257: 5229.5, 258: 5230.0, 259: 5230.5, 260: 5231.0, 261: 5231.5, 262: 5232.0, 263: 5232.5, 264: 5233.0, 265: 5233.5, 266: 5234.0, 267: 5234.5, 268: 5235.0, 269: 5235.5, 270: 5236.5, 271: 5237.0, 272: 5237.5, 273: 5238.0, 274: 5238.5, 275: 5239.0, 276: 5239.5, 277: 5240.0, 278: 5240.5, 279: 5241.0, 280: 5241.5, 281: 5242.0, 282: 5242.5, 283: 5243.0, 284: 5243.5, 285: 5244.0, 286: 5244.5, 287: 5245.0, 288: 5246.0, 289: 5246.5, 290: 5247.0, 291: 5247.5, 292: 5248.0, 293: 5248.5, 294: 5249.0}, 'quantity': {0: 20, 1: 40, 2: 10, 3: 90, 4: 20, 5: 25, 6: 85, 7: 305, 8: 75, 9: 10, 10: 150, 11: 150, 12: 215, 13: 155, 14: 80, 15: 55, 16: 255, 17: 180, 18: 205, 19: 250, 20: 140, 21: 210, 22: 130, 23: 235, 24: 400, 25: 180, 26: 275, 27: 675, 28: 240, 29: 250, 30: 145, 31: 255, 32: 350, 33: 205, 34: 180, 35: 265, 36: 100, 37: 390, 38: 150, 39: 145, 40: 425, 41: 450, 42: 305, 43: 250, 44: 155, 45: 685, 46: 585, 47: 665, 48: 500, 49: 425, 50: 320, 51: 340, 52: 320, 53: 795, 54: 550, 55: 850, 56: 895, 57: 685, 58: 320, 59: 420, 60: 280, 61: 535, 62: 375, 63: 425, 64: 25, 65: 705, 66: 640, 67: 515, 68: 260, 69: 650, 70: 305, 71: 315, 72: 160, 73: 525, 74: 160, 75: 355, 76: 65, 77: 230, 78: 45, 79: 180, 80: 95, 81: 350, 82: 20, 83: 295, 84: 15, 85: 125, 86: 60, 87: 225, 88: 40, 89: 110, 90: 100, 91: 40, 92: 40, 93: 110, 94: 110, 95: 110, 96: 50, 97: 10, 98: 155, 99: 15, 100: 135, 101: 20, 102: 105, 103: 215, 104: 290, 105: 260, 106: 195, 107: 105, 108: 45, 109: 45, 110: 40, 111: 95, 112: 185, 113: 70, 114: 265, 115: 105, 116: 300, 117: 100, 118: 375, 119: 100, 120: 265, 121: 265, 122: 520, 123: 285, 124: 530, 125: 270, 126: 805, 127: 430, 128: 400, 129: 340, 130: 485, 131: 160, 132: 720, 133: 370, 134: 465, 135: 1250, 136: 890, 137: 310, 138: 810, 139: 455, 140: 815, 141: 525, 142: 600, 143: 300, 144: 375, 145: 265, 146: 690, 147: 115, 148: 60, 149: 125, 150: 455, 151: 290, 152: 20, 153: 115, 154: 25, 155: 20, 156: 80, 157: 60, 158: 110, 159: 60, 160: 65, 161: 100, 162: 100, 163: 20, 164: 15, 165: 30, 166: 150, 167: 15, 168: 50, 169: 85, 170: 265, 171: 180, 172: 15, 173: 15, 174: 20, 175: 95, 176: 70, 177: 55, 178: 360, 179: 295, 180: 665, 181: 330, 182: 390, 183: 225, 184: 680, 185: 215, 186: 135, 187: 120, 188: 215, 189: 75, 190: 420, 191: 210, 192: 250, 193: 110, 194: 155, 195: 125, 196: 145, 197: 25, 198: 375, 199: 10, 200: 30, 201: 10, 202: 120, 203: 75, 204: 60, 205: 55, 206: 55, 207: 140, 208: 265, 209: 175, 210: 190, 211: 80, 212: 145, 213: 225, 214: 45, 215: 85, 216: 185, 217: 70, 218: 215, 219: 130, 220: 345, 221: 125, 222: 55, 223: 165, 224: 200, 225: 80, 226: 125, 227: 235, 228: 385, 229: 280, 230: 605, 231: 695, 232: 860, 233: 175, 234: 450, 235: 200, 236: 625, 237: 160, 238: 260, 239: 60, 240: 175, 241: 130, 242: 45, 243: 480, 244: 220, 245: 90, 246: 315, 247: 20, 248: 585, 249: 105, 250: 40, 251: 85, 252: 120, 253: 205, 254: 105, 255: 225, 256: 745, 257: 255, 258: 775, 259: 105, 260: 615, 261: 155, 262: 370, 263: 315, 264: 100, 265: 35, 266: 190, 267: 70, 268: 585, 269: 85, 270: 75, 271: 80, 272: 295, 273: 35, 274: 165, 275: 175, 276: 190, 277: 575, 278: 200, 279: 140, 280: 65, 281: 80, 282: 75, 283: 55, 284: 265, 285: 155, 286: 10, 287: 150, 288: 60, 289: 115, 290: 150, 291: 30, 292: 150, 293: 20, 294: 55}}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dct)

# Make data 1-dimensional
data_1d = np.array(np.repeat(data.price, data.quantity)).reshape(-1, 1)

# Cluster
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=5000, min_samples=200)
clusterer.fit(data_1d)

# Merge the cluster labels to data and re-groupby `price`
clustered_data_1d = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((data_1d, clusterer.labels_.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1), columns=['price', 'cluster'])
clustered_data_1d['quantity'] = 1
grouped_data_1d = clustered_data_1d.groupby('price').agg({'cluster': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], 'quantity': np.sum}).reset_index()

# Plot
fig = px.bar(grouped_data_1d, x='price', y='quantity', color='cluster', orientation='v')
fig.update_traces(dict(marker_line_width=0))
fig.show()
```

Comment: As an ML beginner: Tons of thanks to you! I had tried filling the area below the function `f(price) =  quantity` with 10 more points for each price equaly spaced, but got stuck to see where this would lead. Your solution is far the best we can achive, the HDBSCAN weighted feature implementation is still in [progress](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/pull/165).
Who wants to study, I also got to solve this with K-means sample weighted and Ckmeans, I will make a new post later showing a comparison among the methods, but HDSCAN is the best for this problem.